# Not able to see Manage External Users under App permission

Tags: user-management, digital-experience

I am trying to enable "Login as Experience user" action in person account. For that I am trying to enable "Manage External user" option under profile but I am not able to view that option , I am not sure what I am missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This article may answer your scenario: [Unable to enable or see Manage External Users permission on profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381170&type=1)

> Depending on User Interface settings, you can check the permission one of two ways:
>
> - If Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface is selected: Setup | Manage Users | Profiles | System Administrator | App Permissions.
>
>   - 'Manage External Users' is in the 'Partner Relationship Management' section.
> - If Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface is NOT selected: Setup | Manage Users | Profiles | System Administrator.
>
>   - 'Manage External Users' is in the 'Administrative Permissions' section.